# Intuition for $E[E[X\vert \mathcal{H}]\vert \mathcal{G}]\not= E[X\vert \mathcal{G}]$ where $\mathcal{G}\supset\mathcal{H}$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

This is just the general Law of iterated Expectations but with the larger sigma-algebra in the outer (instead of the inner) expectation.

I am wondering if anyone can provide some intuition for why this is not true?

Mathematically I am thinking about it as the outer expectation must be equal to the inner expectation (which equals $E[X]$) for all subsets of $\mathcal{G}$. But this leaves some subsets of $\mathcal{H}$  where the inner and outer expectation can disagree (and thus the outer one is not necessarily $E[X]$ on those sets).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $E(X\mid \mathcal{H})$ is $\mathcal{H}$ measurable and thus $\mathcal{G}$ measurable,
\begin{align*}
E\left(E(X\mid\mathcal{H})\mid\mathcal{G}\right) = E(X\mid\mathcal{H}),
\end{align*}
which is generally not equal to $E(X\mid\mathcal{G})$, if $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are not equal.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with this answer. I am not accepting it, however (for now at least), in hopes that someone else is able to provide a more intuitive answer.